# Enabling/Disabling onsen Button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

i want to enable/disable onsen buttons on click event of other button. 
i have used following code for that but it didn't worked for me. 
need suggestions/corrections for the same.

```
 <ons-button id="save" disabled="true">Save</ons-button>
 <ons-button id="edit" ng-click ="edit_click()">Edit</ons-button>
 <ons-button id="cancel" disabled="true">Cancel</ons-button>
```

javascript :

```
function edit_click(){ 
document.getElementById("save").disabled="false";
document.getElementById("cancel").disabled="false";
}
```

Comment: `"false" !== false` :-) You need `elem.disabled = false;` instead (without quotes)

Comment: Using false without quotes also didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngAttrDisabled` directive to disable buttons dynamically.

```
<ons-button ng-attr-disabled="{{ disableButton }}">Click me!</ons-button>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="disableButton">
```

Unfortunately `ngDisabled` doesn't work in the current version of Onsen UI for the `<ons-button>` tag.

Comment: this indeed worked but didn't served my purpose. I want the same operation under click event of another onsen button. No idea how to do that.

Comment: Just do `ng-click="disableButton = !disableButton"` to disable it when you click a button.

Comment: great !! it works. 
but still, this limits the click event to only 1 operation. 
what if i want to do some other tasks under same click event ?

Comment: You should write a controller. Please look at the AngularJS docs.

Comment: it's done !!
"disableButton = !disableButton" trick did all my work. 
thanks a ton ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are evaluating "false" `string` value not `boolean` value...

```
function edit_click(){ 
    document.getElementById("save").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("cancel").disabled=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a proper example in angularjs doc with directive ng-disable: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

You can try similar one with onsen:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
<ons-button ng-model="button" disabled="{{checked}}">Button</button>
```

Comment: this guide is for simple html button.
i want to toggle onsen buttons.

Comment: Look at sample of code I provide above. It is for onsen button. I test it before posting here. It works well...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular it is easy to do and reliable. Following code worked for me, check it out =)

**html**

```
<ons-button modifier="outline" style="width: 100%; ng-disabled="isDisable">Print</ons-button>

<ons-button modifier="outline" style="width: 100%; ng-disabled="isDisable">Email</ons-button>
```

**js**

```
//to disable
$scope.isDisable = true;

//to enable
$scope.isDisable = false;
```